# Marklogic versioning

Tags: version, marklogic, patch, marklogic-10

I'm new to ML and have a versioning question. My company is running 10.0-8.5. Is the 10.0-8 the version and .5 is the patch or is 10.0 the version and 8.5 is the patch? I've heard both at work and can't find anything on ML's website with dates to point me in the right direction.

I've researched this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versioning of MarkLogic server with dashes has been a little confusing, but 10.0-8 was first and 10.0-8.5 was last.

- 10.0-8
- 10.0-8.1
- 10.0-8.2
- 10.0-8.3
- 10.0-8.4
- 10.0-8.5
- 10.0-9

MarkLogic has embraced [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/release-notes/en/what-s-new-in-marklogic-11.html

> Beginning with version 11.0.0, MarkLogic Server is adopting the industry-standard Semantic Versioning number system. From this point forward, all public releases will use a 3-part version string, where the parts represent, respectively, MAJOR, MINOR, and PATCH releases, with respect to compatibility of public APIs.
>
> - A release that increments only the PATCH version indicates that incorrect behaviors, what are considered "bugs", have been fixed or that security patches have been applied, but no compatibility changes are present
> - A release that increments the MINOR version indicates that additional functionality has been included, but existing public APIs remain compatible
> - A release that increments the MAJOR version indicates that additional functionality has been included and there are potentially breaking changes to one or more public APIs

The MarkLogic 11 releases are more standard:

- 11.0.0
- 11.0.1
- 11.0.2
- 11.0.3
- 11.1.0

Comment: So will there be a 10.0-8.6 or would we version up to 10.0-9.... or to the 10.0-10.2 that's listed as the supported version?

Comment: 10.0-11 is the latest available, just released. If you are going to upgrade, go with the latest and greatest. Those older versions weren't as good about isolating features and breaking changes from bug and security fixes as they should have been. With Semantic Versioning and a new Long Term Support strategy, it will be more clear which versions have fixes only and which have new features.

Comment: Thank you. Our lead DBA keeps saying that there will be another patch at the 10.0-8.x level, but it's been a dozen months at least since it's been patched and that doesn't match the cadence from others I've talked to.

Comment: regarding:  "... Our lead DBA keeps saying that there will be another patch at the 10.0-8.x level, ..."  There is no reason to assume this.